# How to call all destructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

i have a big problem. When i throw an exception or call std::terminate or std::exit, the object destructor does not runs. Well this is the problem, my code is full of with this statements, because i was thinking this statements are calling destructor.

How i can solve this problem? I can not change the structure of the classes, i have 10K of code and many classes.

```
void Function(int Stage)
{
    switch (Stage)
    {
        case 0: 
            //Somehow call the destructors
            break;
        case 1:
            //initialize
            break;
        default:
           //Give an error message and call the destructors
   }
}
```

Comment: What kind of object? How are they constructed? How do you know the destructor is not called? Please edit your code with a [MCVE](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimx-ihn9fOAhWGWxQKHYyZDVsQFghNMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&usg=AFQjCNEkKReghNZHBJSaky_hwPskMmG0ww&sig2=ryrpHSHDOO-4HSaxfTgj1w)

Comment: Read up on smart pointers. Will save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: Add an exception handler to `main()` and don't call `std::terminate` call `std::exit` or better still *throw an exception*.

Comment: @Galik thank you, you save my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructors should run automatically upon exceptions etc.., this is exactly why they were invented in the first place.

Perhaps you created you objects using `new`? In which case you need to `delete` them explicitly (and then the destructors will run).

Comment: The destructors won't necessarily be called if no exception handler is found; it's implementation defined.